# Create a new list in a list of lists that has the same length as the longest one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

If I have the following list of lists:

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

Is there a way to create a list between the second and third one (preferably at any position) that has the same length as the longest list in this list of lists?

For example, in my case create a list between the second and third/last list that has the same length as the last one (since this is the longest list with length 7):

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

I'm using this data in a dataframe with pandas. Maybe pandas can help me accomplish my goal?

Comment: why do you want to insert the new list in the second to last position and how do you want to construct the new list?

Comment: `data.insert(2, max(data, key=len).copy())`?

Comment: @HenryWoody it's just the right column place. It's getting exported to a csv file. The elements in this new list don't matter. It can be all the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the longest sublist, then create a new list of that length (by copying it or whatever you need). Then insert the new list into `data` at your desired position.

```
data = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

longest_sublist = max(data, key=len)
new_list = longest_sublist.copy()

desired_position = 2
data.insert(desired_position, new_list)
```

After which, `data` becomes:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Being that no specific elements for the new list have been provided, you could simply make a copy of the longest sublist and then `insert` it into `data`

```
data = sorted(data, key=len) # for when lists are not organized by len

new = ['x']*len(data[-1])
data.insert(-1, new)
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite simple

```
def insert_sublist(list_of_lists, position):
    ideal_sized_list = list(range(max([len(i) for i in list_of_lists])))
    return list_of_lists[:position]+[ideal_sized_list]+list_of_lists[position:]
```